# Change the background color of an iDraw file?

Tags: transparency, background, idraw

I have an iDraw document and I want to make the background transparent.  How can I do that in iDraw?

Answer (score 2):

1)  Select the Window menu at the top.
2)  Select properties.
3)  Under properties, change the background

Comment: I think your answer would be better and receive an upvote if you included images/examples.